# How do I keep a running total of an input variable inside of a switch?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am pretty new to C++. I am working on a program where a user can withdraw or deposit money into a virtual ATM. I have four cases in my switch, and I am trying to track every amount that the user deposits. My goal is to not allow the user to deposit more that $1000 throughout the entirety of the switch - whether that is $1000 as a single deposit, or two $500 deposits, etc.

I have only had luck using my nested if statements as you will see below, by saying "if(deposit > 1000)" but this only takes care of the case where they enter a value greater than 1000, not if they do multiple deposits and enter 400 then 600 for example.

```
 case 3:

 cout << "Deposit - How much would you like to deposit? $";

        cin >> deposit;



        if (deposit >= 0 && deposit <=50) {

        cout << "Your new balance after depositing $" << deposit <<    " will be $"
             << (balance += deposit) << '\n' <<endl;
        }
        else if (deposit < 0 )

        {
            cout << "Please enter a postive value." << endl;
        }

       else if (balance + deposit > 3495.99)

        {
           cout<< "You have exceeded the maximum balance your  account can hold. Please enter a smaller deposit amount.";
       }

        else if (deposit > 50)
        cout << "Please note: There is a $2.50 fee for deposits  over $50. Your new balance after depositing $" << deposit << " will be  $"
             << (balance += (deposit - over50fee )) <<'\n'  <<endl;


cout << "Would you like to take any other actions today? Y/N ";
```

If the user enters a total deposit amount (regardless of how many deposits) of greater than $1000, I would like to print the message "The maximum daily deposit limit has been reached. Please deposit up to $1000."

I would appreciate any help that you can provide!

Thank you!

Comment: There is no `switch` in your code.

Comment: Try using `std::vector` to track each deposit, use `std::accumulate` to find the total sum of deposits before committing any more deposits.

Comment: @melpomene There's a case statement, which implies a switch statement. But you bring a good point. It may be helpful to see the whole switch statement.

Comment: I suggest you create a function and call it with appropriate parameters rather than sticking all that code within a `case` statement.  I can bet that entire code you are showing us (and not showing us) is one monstrous `if` and `switch` statements, making it hard to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You can introduce an additional variable say `depositTracker`. Initialise it to 0. `
Then try this:

```
cin >> deposit;
depositTracker += deposit;
if (depositTracker > 1000) {
  cout << " You have reached your maximum deposit limit";
}
```

This way, each time you deposit, it will add the amount to `depositTracker`. If the sum of deposits exceeds 1000, it will tell the user.
Hope this helps.